# Linking Specific part of Image which is in Background

Tags: html, xhtml, css

I have a Background Image [through CSS], I want to Link a Specific Part of that Image like it says "Home" and I want to point it to my site's home.

I think the Image Mapping works only with normal images and I can't find a way to do it with Background Image [Actually I haven't tried.]

So Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

Thanks :)

Comment: add an "a" tag in your markup. Position it using absolute that it sits directly on the top of the part where it says Home. Hide it using visibility: hidden.

Comment: @Jawad Can you tell me any software that tells the position of a part in webpage? Manually I would go MAD.

Comment: please give some code with what we can work. post your markup and CSS. an JSfiddle would be great.

Comment: @Jawad I did that alquatoun's answer - <a href="http://www.x.com/" alt="x.com"><img border="0" src="images/blank.gif" alt="x's Logo" width="100" height="50px"/></a> But it shifts the Text...

Comment: Open the image in Photoshop. Track a measureable line to find out the distnace from the top and left of the "home" part in the image. It should tell you how much down the and how much left the "home" is in pixels.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a 1px transparent png over the background image
2. Set the size of the png to the size of the background or link you want to make
3. Now you can either just link that transparent png, or map it

If you're having trouble fitting the png in the space, float it or use position:relative to get the overlaying transparent image to where you need it.

Comment: I used a gif image 1px; But it shifts the text... :(

Comment: depending on where your elements are, you can float your gif on one side or the other, then relative position and move it over where you want the link to be.  See http://jsfiddle.net/Cweg5/

Comment: It's in that fiddle example, but basically you'll have to add it to the gif.

Comment: For example...    float:right;position:relative;right:400px;top:30px;  
The float will take it out of the containing element so the text will be in the right place, then relative position will let you position the gif in the right spot

Comment: This is a much better solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have

HTML

```
<div>
<a href="#home"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div
{
width: 100px; /*the same width of the background image*/
height: 100px; /*the same height of the background image*/
background-image: url("#image");
position: relative;
}

div>a
{
position: absolute;
top: 10px /*the distance of the "home" part of the image from the top*/
left: 20px /*the distance of the "home" part of the image from left*/
width: 10px /*the width of the "home" part of the image*/
height: 5px /*the height of the "home" part of the image*/
display: block;
}

div>a:hover
{
outline: 1px solid black;
}
```